# Let $x$ be transcendental over $F$. Let $y=f(x)/g(x)$ be a rational function. Prove $[F(x):F(y)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

Let $F$ be a field and $x$ transcendental over $F$. Let $y=f(x)/g(x)$ be a nonconstant rational function with relatively prime polynomials $f,g\in F[x]$. Prove $[F(x):F(y)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$.

**My attempt:** By replacing $y$ with $\frac{1}{y}$ if necessary we assume $\deg g\geq\deg f$. By the Euclid algorithm we assume $\deg g>\deg f$. Then $\deg g=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$, let $n=\deg g$. Let $R(t)$ be this polynomial
$$R(t)=yg(t)-f(t)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(t)-f(t)$$
Then $\deg R=\deg g=n$ because $n=\deg g>\deg f$. The coefficients of $R(t)$ lie in $F(y)$ and hence $R(t)\in F(y)[t]$. Clearly $R(x)=0$.

Now I only have to prove
$R(t)$ is actually the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $F(y)$. I believe the next step is to obtain a contradiction that $R(t)$ being reducible can lead to $f,g$ being not coprime, but I can't figure out how to do that.

P.S. A hint is preferred over a full answer.

Comment: what did you exactly meant by "y replacing y with 1/y "in 1st line of ypur attempt. Can you please explain?

Comment: How can it be proved that   the Euclid algorithm implies that  we assume deg g>deg f?  Can you please explain ?

Comment: @No-One To your 1st comment: We are considering field extensions, so it doesn't matter whether you extend $F$ with $y$ or $1/y$, i.e. $F(y)=F(1/y)$, since a field must contain the inverse of any nonzero element. To your 2nd comment: Now that we've assumed $\deg g\geq\deg f$, either their degrees are equal or not. If equal, then $f(x)=cg(x)+r(x)$, where $c\in F$ is the quotient of the coefficients of the highest-degree terms in $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and $\deg r<\deg g$. So $y=c+r(x)/g(x)$. Again, $c\in F$ doesn't matter in field extensions, i.e., $F(y)=F(y-c)$ for $c\in F$.

Comment: I understood your comment completely that if degrees are equal then f(x)= c g(x) + r(x), then y  can be written as  equal to c +r(x)/g(x). But you didn't concluded your comment.

Comment: what were you trying to prove?

Comment: @No-One The conclusion is that __"we can assume $\deg f<\deg g$ in the problem statement."__

Comment: @No-One More precisely, we have these equivalences: (i) $[F(x):F(y)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)\iff[F(x):F(1/y)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)$. (ii) When $f=cg+r$ as above, $[F(x):F(y)]=\max(\deg f,\deg g)\iff[F(x):F(y-c)]=\max(\deg r,\deg g)$. Note that these equivalences are obtained by plain notation substitution.

Comment: " Got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Since $x$ is transcendental over $F$, we get that $y$ is also transcendental. In particular, $F[y]$ is a UFD, therefore to show that $R$ is irreducible in $F(y)[t]$, it is enough to show that it is irreducible in $F[y][t]$ by Gauss' lemma.

But then $F[y][t]  = F[t][y]$, so you can act like $y$ is a variable and we can take the $y$ degrees during comparison of equality in this integral domain. What is the $y$ degree of $R(t)$?

To finish, what is the $t$ degree of $R$?

Comment: Got it. If $R(t)$ has a factorization in $F[y,t]$ then one of the factors must have degree $0$ in $y$. Divide $R(t)$ by this factor one yields a polynomial, meaning this factor is common factor of $f,g$. But they are coprime hence the factor must be a constant. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely fine!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon  Kindly  Consider the question of mine to which this question was linked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892330/finding-degree-of-field-extension . So, you are giving the proof that R(t) is actually minimal polynomial of x over F(y).So, your answer starts by using that x is transcendental over F. But In my question such is not the assumption. So, Can you please tell how should I proceed? I understood most of attempt of user: trisct.

Comment: @No-One Will take a look, thanks. Possibly not today, but tomorrow if possible.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It's Ok. No hurries.